# How to root cyanogen OS? (On Wileyfox swift)

Tags: rooting

I would like to know how to root Cyanogen OS on WileyFox Swift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply by flashing [SuperSU](https://download.chainfire.eu/696/supersu/).<sup>**1**</sup> There's a [thread at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wileyfox-swift/general/root-wileyfox-swift-t3261321) explaining the steps:

1. download SuperSu
2. save it to your external sdcard
3. enable developer options (settings - about - click mutliple times on the build number)
4. enable OEM unlock in the developer options settings on the device
5. reboot Wileyfox Swift into fastboot mode: with the device powered down, hold the <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> and connect USB
6. to unlock the boot loader **(WARNING!!! This wipes your user data!!!),** type from your computer:

   ```
   fastboot oem unlock
   fastboot -i 0x2970 oem unlock-go
   fastboot oem unlock-go
   ```
7. download latest recovery image [from Cyanogen](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=crackling)
8. to boot the custom recovery, on your computer type

   ```
   fastboot boot <name_of_recovery>.img
   ```
9. install supersu update zip from recovery menu (choose zip from extenal SD)
10. reboot and enjoy root access

Note that steps 6 and 8 require the matching drivers being installed on your computer if you run Windows.

#### Updating a rooted Swift

Also note that "incremental updates" are no longer working with the device rooted. Please see [how to update rooted fox](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wileyfox-swift/general/rom-wileyfox-swift-t3267037) at XDA for alternatives. Each of those updates will probably break root, so you'll have to repeat the above procedure after each update to regain root access.

Alternatively, you can also switch from *CyanogenOS* to [CyanogenMod](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=crackling&type=snapshot), which includes root access.

---

<sup>**1:** Note that's not the latest version – but the one reported working at the time of that post. The always [latest version is available here](http://download.chainfire.eu/supersu).</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39827/discussion-on-answer-by-izzy-how-to-root-cyanogen-os-on-wileyfox-swift).

Answer (score 1):

Izzy's answer is great.  A couple of additions - I hit an issue where my device would not Boot past the TWRP Recovery tool.  If you hit the same roadblocks make sure:

- **Use TWRP version 3.2.0.4 or newer**.  The previous version I used did not work.  You can choose your Custom Recovery tool.  I used TWRP instead of CWM.
- I followed these instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaK5OxUeDKM.  Key points: Wipe data first, via TWRP. Use **Advanced Wipe** and select **Cache, Dalvik/Art Cache, System** and **Data**
- You can use adb sideload from TWRP (select the Advanced button). Make sure you **install the rooted ROM and the gapps zip files** before you reboot.

If it helps, I was running the non-rooted Cyanogen O/S.  You download the rooted version from: `https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=crackling`. I found the newest version of TWRP on xda-forums.  Then I used adb sideload to get the new version of TWRP onto my device.